# Result<usize, std::io::error::Error> does not implement expect in Rust 1.0.0

Tags: rust

In the "Guessing Game" tutorial example ([here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/guessing-game.html)), my compiler is giving the following error, which I interpreted to mean that `expect` doesn't exist on `read_line`'s `Result`.

```
error: type `core::result::Result<usize, std::io::error::Error>` does not implement any method in scope named `expect`
```

The offending code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("**********************");
    println!("***Guess the number***");
    println!("**********************");

    let mut guess = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut guess)
        .expect("Failed to read line"); //<<-- error on this line
    //let guess_result=io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess);

    println!("You guessed: {}", guess);
    // println!("Result: {}", guess_result.is_ok());
}
```

I can remove the line(s) with `.expect()`and use the commented lines above and get it working.  My concern is that it looks like the resulting type from `io::stdin().read_line` is `core::result::Result` and not the `std::io::Result` mentioned in the tutorial.

If I run that same code on the Rust playground it seems to run fine, so it's probably something in my environment, but I can't think what it could be.

Other possibly-relevant information:

- I'm behind a corporate proxy that re-signs SSL certs, so the install script recommended by the rust-lang website didn't work
- I installed using `rust-1.0.0-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.msi`
- I'm using the cargo included in the above "1.0.0" installer
- I've manually added the path to rustc and cargo to my environment `PATH`
- I'm using cygwin on 64-bit Windows 7

***TL;DR***

What do I need to change so that the `expect()` line compiles in my environment?

Comment: Rust 1.0.0 is over a year old. Uninstall that, and try the latest stable version: https://static.rust-lang.org/dist/rust-1.11.0-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu.msi. I don't know if that's the root issue, but it can't hurt to be up to date!

Comment: And for future reference, the installers for the latest version of Rust can always be downloaded from https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/downloads.html. You don't need to use the shell script (although if you can, it's better, as rustup.sh lets you install multiple versions of the compiler in parallel)!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rust 1.0 was released on 2015-05-15, over one year prior. While Rust 1.x aims for *backwards compatibility* (code written on Rust 1.x should work on Rust 1.(x+1)), it does **not** aim for *forwards compatibility* (code written on Rust 1.x should work for Rust 1.(x-1)).

Reading the documentation for Rust 1.11 (the current release) is not going to be the most useful thing if you are limited to Rust 1.0.

Your **best** bet is to [update to the newest version of Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/en-US/downloads.html).

That being said, the [documentation for Rust 1.0 is available online](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/) (I think you also have a copy of it installed locally). Checking out [the guessing game](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/book/guessing-game.html), we see:

```
io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .ok()
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

That is, we convert from a `Result` to an `Option`. Checking out the API for [`Result` in 1.0.0](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/result/enum.Result.html), we can see that it indeed doesn't have an `expect` method.

If you check the [current docs for `Result::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect), you can see that it was introduced in Rust 1.4.

Comment: Ahah.  I'm pulling down the latest version now; thanks!  Now I'm wondering where I got this link to version 1.0.0; I can't find it when I retrace my steps.

Answer (score 1):

The `expect()` method for `Result<T, E>` was introduced only in Rust 1.4.0 ([source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect)).